# Laravel - Queue Jobs - How to get a job based on the argument passed to it when dispatching

Tags: php, laravel, cron, jobs

I have multiple records in my accounts table. and I have one job let's call it `MasterJob` triggered every 5 minutes minutes. this job handle function will loop through my accounts and dispatch `jobA` for each of those accounts. eg: `dispatch JobA($accountId1), dispatch JobA($accountId2)..etc.`

here is a code sample:

```
class MasterJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle()
    {
       $accounts = Account::all();
       foreach($accounts as $account)
       {
           JobA::dispatch($account); 
           //$account has all the details of the record including id and other details
       }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when `JobA(1)` takes more than 5minutes to process. in this case, the `MasterJob` is triggered again and therefore it will dispatch another `JobA($accountId1)` even though the previous one isn't fully processed.

What i want to achieve is: don't dispatch only those that are still processed. for example: don't dispatch `JobA(1)` again, but u can dispatch `JobA(2)` and `JobA(3)` without a problem.

the only thing i found was the `withoutOverlapping()` function but it's not helpful in my scenario. is there anyway i can check that a job for that account isn't running before i dispatch it again?

BTW, I am using database as the queue driver.